# Magento 2 Home Page : Show Products by Category

Tags: categories, magento2, product

I have created some custom category.All of them is visible in home page however when i click on any of the category it will redirect me to category html page with blank screen the products that belong to that category is not visible.

I also tried to change **admin->products->categories->Custom Design** of each Category and also set Use Parent Category Settings to Yes for each category but is not working,the same result i m getting (Blank Screen)[All Category is showing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hC4XD.png)

Answer (score 0):

Go to admin panel admin > catalog > manage categories > mycategory > Custom Design and selecting my layout manually in the dropdown for each categories. 
Also from Admin -> Catalog -> Category -> Custom Design I should have set Use Use Parent Category Settings to Yes.

Comment: I also try this but its not working for me.Is there any other way to solve this problem?